# Generators, yield, send python

Tags: python, generator, yield

I got this homework question, after taking a course on udemy I still cannot figure out how to solve it.
It is about yield, next and send.

This is what I need to do:
Guidance:

1. Use `itertools.permutations` to produce all permutations of the list, and store them in a
   permutations list
2. Sort the permutations list using `list.sort()`
3. Use `yield` keyword while iterating over the permutations list
4. Check if the `yield` statement obtained an input list, if so, empty the permutations list and repeat step 2

Below there is the code i tried, it doesn't support the send function and keeps going with the old LIST.

```py
def permute(items):
    permu_list = [perm for perm in pr(items)]
    permu_list.sort()
    for x in permu_list:
        yield x
```

this is the exmaple of results:

```
>>> g = permute(['b', 'a', 'c'])
>>> next(g)
('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> next(g)
('a', 'c', 'b')
>>> g.send(['e', 'q', 'c'])
('c', 'e', 'q')
>>> next(g)
('c', 'q', 'e')
```

Comment: Ty for the help. How to do that? I kinda get this whole generators thing hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value which has been sent by assignment in the yield statement.
like:

```
received = yield something
```

For your usage you need an extra knowledge you can yield from another generator by `yield from` statement. in your case you need something like this:

```
def permute(items):
    permu_list = [perm for perm in pr(items)]
    permu_list.sort()
    for x in permu_list:
        l = yield x
        if l:
            yield from permute(l)
            break
```

In line which have `l = yield x` I receive whatever has been sent to this generator if you simply call next on a generator you receive `None` here, so I wrote an if statement to check whether it's a `None` value or it's something which comes from send method of generator.

After that I create and use another generator from the same generator function which we got. By `permute(l)` I create a new generator and by `yield from` I send output of this generator as output and after that I don't want to continue generating permutation from the first list so I break the loop.

For more information you can check [this two parted article](http://simeonvisser.com/posts/python-3-using-yield-from-in-generators-part-1.html).

Comment: Tyvm! Could you explain a little more how does it work and why you did what you did? Hard for me to understand it, seems way more advanced from what we learned lol